# vector summation done in matrix form (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, variance

I want to prove the following

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\vec{x_i} \cdot \vec{w})^2 = (xw)^T (xw)$

where $\vec{x_i}$ is a $1\times p$ vector and $\vec{w}$ is a $p\times 1$ vector. If we stack our $n$ data vectors $\vec{x_i}$ we get an $n\times p$ matrix that we denote by $x$

a simple example for these unknowns (with $n=p=2$) might be:

$\vec{x_1} = <1,2>$
$\vec{x_2} = <3,4>$

$x = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 2\\ 3& 4 \end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{w} = \begin{bmatrix}
 2 \\
2 
\end{bmatrix}
$

By replacing both sides of the first equation with this example, I was able to verify the equality. However, I am looking for a mathematical proof or an explanation of the linear algebra rules that were used to transform the left hand side of the equation to the right hand side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's let $x_{ij}$ denote the $j$th entry of $x_i$. Then it also happens to denote the entry in row $i$, column $j$ of the matrix you're calling $x$. Using $w_k$ to denote the $k$th entry of $w$, the left hand side is
\begin{align}
\sum_i (x_i \cdot w)^2 
&=\sum_i \left(\sum_k [(x_i)_k w_k]^2 \right) \\
&=\sum_i \left(\sum_k (x_{ik} w_k)^2 \right)\\
&=\sum_i \left[ (\sum_k (x_{ik} w_k)) (\sum_p (x_{ip} w_p)) \right] \\
&=\sum_i ( (xw)_i) ( (xw)_i) \\
&=(xw) \cdot (xw)\\
&=(xw)^t (xw)\\
\end{align}
where the last step comes from the fact that for any two column vectors $u$ and $v$, $u \cdot v = u^t v$, and $(xw)_i$ denotes the $i$th entry of the matrix-vector product $xw$.

Comment: I think there is a missing parenthesis at line 2 before the square. Also at line 3 you used sum over $p$ by I think it should be the sum over $k$. Nonetheless, this was very helpful

Comment: Parenthesis: fixed. The sum over $p$ was intentional: the name of an index variable is irrelevant to the sum (this is essentially the discrete form of the substitution $x = t, dx = dt$ in an integral!), but using the same index twice can lead to confusion, so I prefer to avoid it.